# Don't understand how to conduct a sugar/water solution experiment

Tags: solutions

I am helping my some with simple chemistry experiments by following a book on experiments. I don't understand how to conduct one experiment thought (please see pic, experiment 16). It says

1. dissolve sugar in hot water till saturation point
2. let the water evaporate.

How will the water evaporate on its own? Will it evaporate on its own even when I am not heating the water?

[image]

Comment: If you washed the floor, would water evaporate spontaneously or would you need to heat it?

Comment: my doubt is that water in beaker would be quite more than the thin layer on the floor. How long it might take to evaporate ?

Comment: Very long time and it is adviced to minimize the depth of the solution. Generally, all crystalization procedures take intentionally very long time for crystals to grow large. You may try to pour some volume into a flat plate or  similar, to have the depth just few mm.

Comment: The answers to your questions are basically in the description you posted.

Comment: How will the water evaporate on it's own... haven't you seen or felt sweat?

Comment: just to be clear, I presumed that I need to use a beaker full of water and create a solution. That caused that confusion about the time it would take to evaporate

Answer (score 1):

Evaporation is not the most efficient way of obtaining sugar crystals, because usual sugar is extraordinarily soluble into water. $100$ mL water dissolves $170$ g sugar at $0°$C. And it dissolves $450$ g sugar at $100$°C.

So if you want to get not too tiny sugar crystals, you better try to get them by cooling down the hot saturated solution. As it may take quite a long time to dissolve $450$ g sugar in $100$ mL water at 100°C, I would start to mix $400$ g sugar and $100$ mL water, heat the whole to boiling temperature, until a nice solution is obtained, and simply let it cool down slowly. If the cooling step is fast, you will obtain a lot of tiny crystals, like the usual sugar powder from the market. If the cooling step is slow, individual crystals can find the time to grow slowly.